# Exception when asking WebService

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, httpwebrequest

I'm facing an incomprehensible situation.

I can't totally access to my webservice.
When i want to consume my webservice a have this error :

> [NullReferenceException: The object reference is not defined to an
>   instance of an object]    System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +390
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +175
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetRouteServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +7
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
>   +152    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +126

My computer : windows 10.

Version Microsoft .NET Framework :4.0.30319; Version ASP.NET :4.7.2556.0

I think this is not a programming error in my code because the webservice work on others computers. this error happens only on my computer.

I find this :https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d72570c0-98ea-41cb-8423-94c96abcb2e8/wcf-service-activation-problem?forum=wcf
on the subject but this hotfix isn't for windows 10 and im not sure these two errors are related

Im not asking what is a nullReferenceException but how to fix my problem in System.ServiceModel.WasHosting.dll.

If anyone knows this error please help me.

Comment: @RandRandom - with 2 pages of generic answers but do you think this one is covered there?

Comment: @renevogt - do you think the OP will find _anything_ useful there?

Comment: @ Youssef - ask again but avoid 'null reference', at least in the title. That invokes too much Pavlov here. Focus on the Hosting issues.

Comment: No, ask again. This isn't likely to reopen.

Comment: oh ok thx for your help @bommelding